# update multiple rows?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update multiple rows.
Like make status=false where status=true and make status=true where id=x

```java
try {
    String where = "id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Id };

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("status", "true");
    db.update(TABLE_PROJECT, initialValues, where, whereArgs);
    db.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception in update query", e.toString());
}
```

Currently what happens i am able to update the status first time but when it comes next time i need to change the previous status to false and then update new one with true. I searched and found that it can be done with switch case but here how can we apply this?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read the old `status` values, you have to do both updates in a single query.
You are correct that this requires a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case); something like this:

```
UPDATE Project
SET status = CASE
             WHEN status = 'true' THEN 'false'
             WHEN id = 'x'        THEN 'true'
             END
WHERE status = 'true' OR id = 'x'  -- don't change other records
```

The `ContentValues` class supports only literal values, not expressions, so you have to use `rawQuery` instead:

```java
db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+TABLE_PROJECT+" "+
            "SET status = CASE "+
            "WHEN status = 'true' THEN 'false' "+
            "WHEN id = ?1         THEN 'true' "+
            "END "+
            "WHERE status = 'true' OR id = ?1",
            new String[] { Id });
```

(This assumes that `id` is a string; if not, you don't need to use parameters.
`?1` is the first parameter.)

Answer (score -3):

```
try {

    String where = "id=? or status=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Id,"false" };

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("status", "true");
    db.update(TABLE_PROJECT, initialValues, where, whereArgs);
    db.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception in update query", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Ok. please describe your question properly. This is what I understood